# How can I get securesocial.currentUser in the Future？

Tags: scala, securesocial

This is my code:

```
def getUser(implicit request:play.api.mvc.Request[Any],env:MyEnviroment): Future[User] = {

  SecureSocial.currentUser.map {
    maybeUser =>
      val userId = maybeUser.map(_.main.userId).getOrElse("unknown")    
      val user: User = UserAccessor.finduserbyid(userId)
      Future.successful(user)
  }

}
```

Comment: So... What is wrong with it? What is it that we are supposed to do with this code?

Answer (score 0):

assuming `SecureSocial.currentUser` returns an `Option`, you probably want something like:

```
SecureSocial.currentUser.map {
    maybeUser =>
      val userId = maybeUser.map(_.main.userId).getOrElse("unknown")    
      val user: User = UserAccessor.finduserbyid(userId)
      Future.successful(user)
  }.getOrElse(Future.failed(new Exception("No current user"))
```